# Xcode Build Script (Build Phases->Run Script) Increment Build Version based on Username(User)

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, unix, build

When compiling a project, this script should increment the Build Version of the Xcode project by one, when the system username matches. Keep in mind that these are just Unix commands in a script (not Applescript, Python, or Perl) inside Target->Build Phases->Run Script in Xcode.

I've done "echo $USER" in terminal. This prints the username of the logged-in user just fine, and it's the same string I placed in the conditional statement in the second block of code.

The first block of code works. The second, which adds the conditional statement, does not.

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$USER
if [ username == "erik" ]; then
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
```

**Syntax concerns:**
  
Parsing of $USER (case sensitive) 
  
Semicolon right after closing bracket in if statement
  
Then statement on same line as if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the script log in the Log Navigator, with your script i've got the following issue:

[image]

I believe the default comparison is case sensitive, to make it not sensitive you can change the username to uppercase/lowercase before comparison:

```
if [ `echo $USER | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]` = "USERNAME" ]; then
echo "Got user check"
fi
```

As you can see I moved $USER to the condition to avoid additional var usage and the script failure.

And the semicolon at `if-then` block is a normal thing, check the [man](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) page. `then` word might be moved to the new line if that is more convenient for you to read.